# AWS CodePipeline, CodeDeploy, SAM and Lambda: how to (inter)connect those?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam

I'm a kind of lost in the documentation.
I want to push Python code to a repo and use CodePipeline to deploy Lambdas.
I have CodeCommit repo, CodePipeline - so far this works and I can create/update CF stack to create supplementary resources.

I know AWS SAM can be used to deploy the functions using CF tpl, but how can I connect SAM with CodePipeline/CodeDeploy? The code should be taken from a 'source' pipeline action then deployed as lambda function.

If SAM isn't the best automated solution here then what should I use instead? Pipeline is the key requirement so we don't have to run something like  `aws cf update-stack` manually, just push the code.

Answer (score 5):

CodePipeline doesn't support deploying Lambda through CodeDeploy, so the approach is to use a CodeBuild Build action to generate an change set from the SAM template and feed it into a CloudFormation Deploy action. You can find a detailed instruction in the following doc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use SAM to deploy Lambdas, CodeDeploy is automatically used.  For reference:

- [Gradual Code Deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/automating-updates-to-serverless-apps.html)
- [Safe Lambda deployments](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/safe_lambda_deployments.rst)